# prevents a class unsetting in php

Tags: php

I created a class implementing ArrayAccess and I added it a function to prevents WRITE actions:

```
 $Obj->Add("key","something");
 $Obj->Add("key2","something2");
 $Obj->SetReadOnly(); // sets read only property
 unset($Obj["key2"]); // throws error, object is readonly
```

But, i want to prevent unsetting object too:

```
 unset($Obj);
```

I can do it?I hear suggestions.
Thanks for help!.

Comment: @FoolishSeth -- I assume he's using the `__unset()` magic method.

Comment: I just realized it's probably in the ArrayAccess implementation.

Comment: Why do you want to prevent top level unset?  It seems like a dangerous and confusing idea.

Comment: When the script ends all the variables will be `unset` throwing the error.

Comment: @FoolishSeth Sets a private $readOnly = TRUE. When  OffsetUnset() method s called and $readOnly === TRUE, throws a exception

Comment: @air4x - not just when the script ends, but even just at the end of the current function, if they variable is in local scope.

Comment: @FoolishSeth Isnt a dangerous idea if you want to prevent unsets system variables in a thirdparty extensions

Comment: @air4x i used OffsetUnset($offset) method of ArrayAccess

Comment: Can you show an example (in code) of the scenario you're trying to prevent?  I feel like there is probably a better way.  Also I don't think there is a straightforward way to stop unset() from working on a top-level variable anyway.

Comment: I was referring to the top level variables. They all are eventually `unset` at the end of the script or when they go out of scope as @spudley pointed out. So throwing error when $Obj is unset is not a good idea.

Comment: You could conditionally throw errors though, using the destructor. Like `function __destruct() { if (//all conditions not met) { throw new Exception('More need to be done before unsetting'); } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't imagine any situation where you would really want to do this.  I can also imagine doing this will cause you serious problems at script termination when all objects are destroyed.  The PHP manual says the following on throwing exceptions in destructors:

> Note:
>
> Attempting to throw an exception from a destructor (called in the time
>   of script termination) causes a fatal error.

The above statement implies that you can throw an exception if you're not in the script termination phase, so maybe the following is possible.

```
public function __destruct ()
{
    if ($this -> isReadOnly ())
    {
        throw new Exception ('Class is read-only');
    }
}
```

However, as the manual points out, this will trigger a fatal error during script shutdown.

I honestly can't see any point to wanting to prevent object destruction.  It should be up to the programmer to manage object lifetimes.

Answer (score 2):

`unset()` does not actually destruct an object, if that's what you're trying to prevent.

An object will only be destructed when all references to it have been unset or are no longer in scope.  Even then it won't happen until the garbage collector runs.

So if you have some code that you are worried will molest your object, you've already done a good job of making it immutable with your read-only logic.

Let's say you have

```
$Obj = gotMyObjectSomehow();
```

and you need to pass it to a some other code you don't want to unset $Obj.  As long as that code is called inside a function, there's nothing to be concerned about.  If you call

```
someFunction($Obj);
```

and let's say that function unsets the parameter it's passed in

```
function someFunction($anObj) {
    unset($anObj);
}
```

then your original `$Obj` variable will still be set.

The function creates a second variable referencing the original object and uses that in its own scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can't control unsetting variable names, because those names are not technically a part of the object referenced. Consider the following:

```
$a = new MyObject();
$b = $a;
```

Now you have *two* references to the same object. There is *no difference* between using `$a` and `$b`, because in PHP objects are always used by reference (i.e. you don't have to do `$b =& $a` in the second line). So both `$a` and `$b` are essentially the same object; unsetting `$a` will not destroy the object, as well as unsetting `$b` won't destroy it; *all* references need to be unset before the object is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do what you're asking for - it's not possible to prevent a variable being unset like that.

However, a comment of yours above set me thinking. You said:

> .... idea if you want to prevent unsets system variables in a thirdparty extensions

So if I understand you right, your aim here is to ensure that while the thirdparty code (ie your software) is in use, all the variables associated with it remain in place?

Now you haven't specified much about what variables there are in this system. We see one object in the question, but presumably there must be more than that? I'm guessing you've got a bunch of things that tie together, right? It would help in these sorts of questions to provide a bit more context; the actual thing that you're asking for isn't possible, but with a bit of understanding about what you want to achieve, we could come up with alternatives.

Okay. So my suggestion: create your objects as Singletons. This is often frowned on by purists, but might work well for this situation, depending on exactly what you're doing. The beauty here is that you can encapsulate all access to the object inside class methods, meaning that the developer using your code doesn't have access to the master copy of the object in order to unset it.

A singleton works like this:

```
<?php
class mySingletonClass {
    private static $masterObject=null;

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!isset(self::$masterObject)) {
            self::$masterObject = new self;
        }
        return self::$masterObject;
    }

    private function __construct() {
        //your existing constructor, as it already exists, but marked as private.
    }

    //...and all the other methods as you already have them.
}
```

The class constructor method is private, so can only be accessed from methods within the class. Therefore, you can no longer do `new classname()`. The only way you can get an object of this class is to get it from the static `getInstance()` method. And the key thing here is that this method always returns the same copy of the object.

```
$obj = mySingletonClass::getInstance();
unset($obj);
$obj = mySingletonClass::getInstance();  //will give the exact same object as the first time.
```

You can unset it if you want, but the original object is still there and can still be accessed. Any of your other classes can use that `getInstance()` method to get the same copy of the same object from anywhere in the program. It's an indestructible global variable.

Singletons are often used for a program's main database connection object, but it might be a useful pattern for you here.

I hope that helps. It's about the only way I can think of to get close to what you want.